# Why does my .htaccess append the query string to the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I have my website set up the following way:

- mysite/site -Goes to the main index.php file
- mysite/site/asdf -Goes to the main index.php file with a subpage
- mysite/site/admin -Goes to an admin panel with various subpages

But the issue I'm running into is when I go to mysite/site/admin without the trailing slash, it appends `/?admin=1` to the URL. Same if I go to mysite/site/admin/pages without the trailing slash, it appends `/?admin=1&page=pages` to the URL. I want it to not append these query strings.

If I add the trailing slash, the query string does not get appended. If I go to mysite/site/admin/pages/edit without the trailing slash, it doesn't append the query string, so it seems just the first 2 levels do this.

This is confusing and I don't understand it at all. I've tried lots of various things from googling and searching this site but nothing has worked. I'm a newbie to this .htaccess stuff. Here's what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/?admin/users/([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=users&subpage=view&user=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?admin/users/create/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=users&subpage=create [L]

    RewriteRule ^/?admin/([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=$1&subpage=$2&id=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?admin/([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=$1&subpage=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?admin/([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?admin/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^/?([\-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: Is `/site/admin/pages` a valid directory?

Comment: @anubhava Yes it is a valid directory but holds all of the pages. It uses admin/index.php to determine the page and include it.

Comment: Oh I'm noticing something now, if I go to mysite/admin/menus without the trailing slash it doesn't append the query string, so it must have to do with the fact that `admin` and `admin/pages` are valid directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `/site/admin/pages` is a valid directory and without trailing slash Apache's `mod_dir` module redirects the URL to one with a trailing slash.

To fix you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^/?admin/users/([-\w]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=users&subpage=view&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?admin/users/create/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=users&subpage=create [L]

RewriteRule ^/?admin/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=$1&subpage=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?admin/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=$1&subpage=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?admin/([-\w]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?admin/?$ admin/index.php?admin=1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/?([-\w]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. The only concern I have now is when I visit mysite/site without the trailing slash, I get a 403 error. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I would like for it to use index.php with no query string.

Comment: I removed the Options -Indexes and it seems to show me `Index of /` instead of the index.php file.

Comment: No, this is the only .htaccess, it is in the root directory of the site.

Comment: It works now, I removed `DirectorySlash Off` to get it working.

Comment: Well, it seems removing `DirectorySlash Off` brings me back to my first problem. It's now appending the query string to `site/admin` and `site/admin/pages` without the trailing slash...

Comment: Yes it's there, the `site` with no slash is working now but is appending the query string again to `site/admin` and `site/admin/pages`